# Is this the seal of Empress Xiaogheghdan, birth Mother of Qianlong Emperor?

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]
This is a large seal, 4" in both height and width, found on a large Chinese Scroll.

The seal seems to refer to the Divine Name given to the Empress Xiaogheghdan, the Birth Mother of Qianlong Emperor (乾隆帝), after her death.

Comment: What make you think this is an "old scroll"?

Comment: There is a toneing to the silk.  Also the painting has been expertly restored in one places.  I do not think that it is 20th Century.

Comment: 重庆精藏之宝。Though the writing of 庆 is rather obscure. 应为贺喜之上贡。

Comment: @TooskyHierot : 庆 ? seems some important part omitted.
http://www.zdic.net/z/19/zy/5E86.htm

Comment: IMHO, you should go find out cultural books on the seals like [鈢印通釋 (1986) or consult experts to checkout the actual items. Without knowing the cultural and behavior of the era (can an emperor mother have her own seal? ), forger can simply make out some story and make a quick bucks.

Comment: @mootmoot http://shufa.guoxuedashi.com/6176/5/ see this their r other variants

Comment: @mootmoot I know you mean the 心 part is lost, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

it's "重" X "精藏之寶"

the bottom right character is, not yet recognised.

Comment: 夢 ? 
http://www.zdic.net/z/1b/zy/68A6.htm